# if-statement typo- I can´t find it

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

```
if (df1 == df2 == df) {
  paste0("same")
} else {
  paste0("differ")
}
```

I want to know if the data.frames have differences. But there is a mistak ein my if-statement. I think it is something with  == as this shows me the error. Where is that "typo" ?

Thank you

Comment: You can't do triple comparison in `R`

Comment: That was fast, and helpful- Thank you ;)

Comment: you need something like `if(df1 == df2 & df1 == df){...}`